# keyhash doesnt get saved on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have developped an app in android intigrating facebook login. everything worked fine until I was in developer mode. But after publishing app login was not working any more. Anyway I learned that I need to put new keyhash from the original keystore. I have got the keystore but when I put that keystore from the developer option and hit save button I get this

[image: screenshot from my developer dashboard]

the red alert button says:

```
Is required if you turn on Single Sign On
```

facebook is not saving my new keyhash and always keeps saying the above message where I was putting my keyhash everytime. What to do now?

Comment: Looks like there is a bug on that page. Please report it on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs . When you input something and click outside the field it should get a box around it. Which there isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. I dont know why facebook removed some of the characters from the string I copied in to that textbox. I manually put all the characters and clicked save and that worked. If I copy paste it from eclipse then It automatically removes from the box, pathetic